# OpenCL global memory vs. image memory performance differences on Nvidia and AMD

Tags: opencl

The OpenCL benchmarking site http://www.clbenchmark.com/ has benchmarks for

```
Image Filter: Separable Gaussian Blur - Global Memory Usage and
Image Filter: Separable Gaussian Blur - Image Memory Usage
```

Nvidia complete dominates on the Global Memory Usage.  For example the GTX 580 is nearlly twice as fast as the HD 7970.  It's one of the few benchmarks where Nvidia still leads.  Can someone explain why this is?

The reason I ask is that I have written a ray tracer on my GTX 590 which runs very fast.  From most reviews I expected my ray tracer to run four times faster on a HD 7970.  However, it actually runs four times slower!  And I don't understand why.  I don't use Image Buffers.  I write out the pixels to global memory.  When I profile the kernel time I see that the HD 7950 kernel time is four times slower so I know the problem is at the kernel side and not when moving data across the PCI bus.

Answer (score 4):

GLobal memory is the device memory, the data buffers which uses global memory have advantage that they can be read and write. they are slow, that is the access to the data buffers consume more gpu cycles.

On the other part texture memory or what you mean image memory is faster than the global memory, they uses less gpu cycles. But they can be read only or write only.

In case you have a situation where you want read only or write only you can use image buffers they are faster. But if you need read-write buffers you are forced to use data buffers(global memory).

Also one more thing to note is that, any read to image buffer can fetch 4 data at a time, if buffer declared RGBA. You can also use this advantage in data buffers if you use float4. Since gpu can access 4 float values in one fetch(this increases the performance).

Always try to use as global memory as less as possible(please do see the NVIDIA or AMD manuals to know exact number of cycles for each memory access). 
Please do let me know if you want more understanding :)

Comment: My question is about why Nvidia appears to be so much faster than AMD with global memory.  The previous generation Fermi GTX 580 is nearly twice as fast as the latest generation Radeon 7970!  Is global memory access much faster on Nvidia?

Can I use image buffers for anything as long as I don't need both read and write?  I mean if I'm processing data that has nothing to with images but I only need to write should/can I used the image buffers?

Comment: You can check that, what is the GPU cycles needed to access global memory in Nvidia and AMD. Yes you can use image buffers as long you dont need read and write. Off course you can use image buffers. Per pixel you can have four channels(RGB), one fetch to image buffers gives you four values, hence much faster.  You are not restricted like only images in image buffers as in OpenGL. if you still have doubt i can provide an example once I go home, for better understanding.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the information.  I had not though to use the image buffers for non-image data.  As I understand one of the advantages of the image buffers is that they are cached.  Constant memory is cached as well but it's much smaller.

Comment: @raxman yes Image buffers advantage is that they are cached, and much better performance than global memory. But can only be read only or write only. So you need to use them based on the requirements.

Comment: In that case global memory should be avoided unless one needs both read/write.  What is the connection between image buffers and global memory on other devices such as CPUs?  Is using image buffers on the CPU the same speed as global memory.  It would be inconvient to have duplicate code.  One for

Comment: Do you know what is done on professional level cards such as Tesla?  Do they have image buffers?  I was under the impression they had no image buffers.  They are not video cards.  I am not sure I can assume devices have image buffers in general.

If you have a lot of data to send to the GPU such as object and ray information that has nothing to do with images do you still use image buffer. I currently use global/constant for that.

It's seems pretty stupid to me if AMD kernels used for example in scientific computing use image buffers most of the time because global memory is so much slower.

Comment: @raxman We call image buffers in opencl, basically it is the texture memory. So any GPU that supports OpenGL do have texture memory. All gpu has texture memory. Always use image buffers or texture memory if it possible in your implementation, it provides performance. Gloabal memory can be read and writable but image buffers are read only or write only, so in opencl we come across situation that more global memory will be used. Again it depends on your implementation. also just imagine 4 global memories can be replaced by 1 image buffer with RGBA channels, which provides good data access rates.